# Product of two matrices

Tags: matrices

[image]

I don't understand what this question is asking me to compute. Judging by the answer space, it's neither a dot product nor multiplication. So what is it?

Comment: Judging by the answer space, it is a multiplication.

Comment: Of course! I confused myself for some ridiculous reason

Comment: It is the outer product of the two vectors

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

$$B_{4\times 1}\cdot A_{1\times 4}=C_{4\times 4}$$

Starting

$$C_{11}=(-4)\cdot (-9)\\
C_{12}=(-4)\cdot (9) ...$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hope it helps.

If you have any questions,  do ask.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

    Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can use LaTeX) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.